# Apple OSX Mavericks

Tags: osx, macosx

I do not normally chase operating systems, but last week I got a new Mac and have not configured it yet.  In addition, Mavericks is being offered as a free upgrade.  So the questions are, has anyone else upgraded to Mavericks yet?  Have you had any "issues", particularly with audio software?  Keen to hear of any issues with the following software:

Pro Tools
Cubase
Logic
Max/MSP
Native Instruments Komplete

Edit: I have just come across the following posts regarding Max/MSP and NI Komplete regarding their OSX 10.9 compatibility:

http://cycling74.com/forums/topic/mac-10-9-mavericks-support/

http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/showthread.php?208864-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks

Answer (score 2):

No experience, old mac running Mountain lion.
But Avid has an article on it: http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/troubleshooting/Mac-OS-10-9-support-for-Media-Composer-Pro-Tools-Sibelius?popup=true&NewLang=en&DocType=1078&q=maverick

So not supported, but if it will work? Make a back up and find out :)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the info.  As it is fresh machine I might give it a go at the weekend and see if it works.  Will report back.

Answer (score 2):

I am using it with Pro Tools 11 on my MacBook Pro and it is lovely and smooth.  I know that Avid advise against Mavericks, but I have found it to be a worthwhile update.

Comment: Iain thanks for the info.  I'm actually on PT10 still at the moment.  Have you (or anyone else up there) tried Max/MSP on it yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running the new OS on my MacBook Pro and Pro Tools seems to be running flawlessly. I haven't tried it on my Mac Pro yet, but I might give it a go next week.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This gives me more confidence.  Are you running PT with the built-in audio hardware or are you using an external audio interface?

Comment: The built-in audio worked great. I was able to use a Presonus Firepod successfully as well, but my 003 didn't work.

Comment: Again thanks for the info.  On my Mac Pro I'm running a 003R so that could be a problem, but it sounds like the MacBook Pro should be ok.  Interesting as in some of our studios we are running Mountain Lion (10.8) and 003R's without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my MacBook Pro to Mavericks, freshly installed Pro Tools 10.3.7 and 11.0.2, with the following issues on built-in audio:

10.3.7
- Cannot create new sessions
- Runs flawlessly on old sessions when you open them.

11.0.2
- Cannot create new sessions
- Crashes immediately after initial loading when attempting to do anything (e.g. changing settings, opening session, ...)
- When frozen after crashing, you cannot force quit. You have to kill and restart the computer.

My advice would be to still wait for the patch before updating.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am still holding off until some of the issues mentioned have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I upgradet yesterday and i can run everything what i used before. a Little bit faster. I like the new features.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded and I can run everything but some small tools (need update as it seems):

- Audiohijack pro, which i use for livestreams
- Effectrix Plug-In

Protools 8 (i know, i should upgrade some time but is the m powered version :D) runs perfect

Ableton runs perfect, but sometimes my mouse (edited from mouth) is vanishing (cmd + alt + esc to get the mouse pointer back)

All other Programs MS Office/ iWork run perfect!

Comment: Sounds like a serious problem if your "mouth is vanishing"!!!!  ;-)

Comment: Hahaha XD my mouse is vanishing haha

Answer (score 0):

No issues with Logic Pro 9 and X, Waves plugins, Native Instruments plug-ins, Ableton Live 8, Mixbus 2.3, Reason 6.5, Triumph or well anything really! I think it's all good to go although with Pro Tools I'd wait or move it to a separate partition/drive.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Of all the software I own I had just assumed that Logic would work.  I'd be seriously worried if Logic had issues.