# Mavericks and pro tools 9

Tags: pro-tools

I was wondering if you could help, I have a copy of pro tools 9 and I would like to update to the new  OS X Mavericks. I know I am pretty behind with pro tools versions I just don't want to have to buy a newer version. Has anybody tried updating to Mavericks and tried to run pro tools 9? I have searched forums but all people are saying is that it is unlikely to work and are not saying whether it does or does not.

Another option for me obviously is to just buy a newer version of pro tools but would really rather not. Is there a cheap way to do it if I have already bought one pro tools?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is your reason to upgrade to mavericks? And what is your current os? In my opinion (mountain lion user) it's not very useful for DAWs.
Regarding pt9, i run it as well and have no issues on ML. No idea how that runs on mavericks. Cheers

Comment: This question is a couple of months old now, but I still have not upgraded: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/apple-osx-mavericks

Comment: Doesn't work my friend. I have mavericks and obtained a copy of protools, and once installed it wasn't compatible. I'm looking for a work around but haven't found it yet.

Comment: Ran it successfully for about three weeks, then started encountering weird errors and rampant CPU leaks. Rolled back to Lion...I doubt Avid will make support for PT9 so it's probably just time to upgrade PT if Mavericks is really important to you.

Comment: Thank you for the info. My real issue is I am on snow leapard still and Mavericks was the free available one. Lion had been made unavailable legally. I will need to find another way to get lion.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Gaelan Timm. so there IS NO PATCH? cos I don't want to waste money on upgrading!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it. I run a PT9 HD3 rig and it made my system freak out. My D-Command Faders (Digidesign pre-avid version) wouldn't even connect anymore. Also lost a large portion of files and backups form my 3rd inboard hard drive thanks to faulty permissions in the time machine backups afterwards. I went back to SL and have basically been running a 2009 system with no problems from updated plugs or anything. It isn't worth upgrading if you are using it solely for recording or mastering. It seems to me that it is only a cosmetic fix and the app problems are taken care of by the Digi core so no worries with latency issues. The cpu leak is probably from the new codes that are designed to shut down background processes that have to run while PT is running. Thus causing an open close error sapping your available memory. Just run ML if it worked for you. I find SL to be the best platform for my PT9 system though.

Concerned mac user and PT freak.